# multiple sql queries vs php filter resultset

Tags: php, mysql, sql, filter, resultset

Let's say there are multiple tabs:

- all rows
- the rows in trash
- the rows that are waiting to be approved

I try to figure out what the best way to create multiple datasets

a - one dataset and then filter them into new ones with PHP

b - multiple queries

The number of rows might vary from just a couple of 100 to 3000.
Is there a best way in the middle to do this?

Comment: Depends how many queries we are talking. You might wish to show us some code in relation to this.

Comment: I guess, you can do all three requests, but limit them to 10 / 25 / 50 / .. etc, and make pagination **or** use ajax and request only one, depends what tab you select (ofc limiting and pagination are preferable)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use that simple solution:

1. SQL

> ```
> SELECT ...,
> IF( [{in-trash} condition], 1, 0) as in_trash,
> IF( [{to-approve} condition], 1, 0) as to_approve
> FROM ...
> ```

2. PHP

> ```
> <?php
> $tabs = cache->get('tabs');
> if( ! $tabs )
> { 
>   $tabs = [ 'all' => [], 'in_trash' => [], 'to_approve' => [],];
>   $rows = mysql->query();
>   foreach( $rows as $row )
>   {
>       $tabs ['all'] [] = $row;
>       if( $row ['in_trash'] )
>       {
>         $tabs ['in_trash'] [] = $row;
>       }
>       if( $row ['to_approve'] )
>       {
>         $tabs ['to_approve'] [] = $row;
>       }
>   }
>   cache->set('tabs', $tabs);
> }
> ?>
> ```